# Any gcc options to treat "int i[]" like "int *i"?

Tags: c, gcc

Older C compilers seem to be more lenient with empty square brackets. Can gcc be made to allow this (even if not standards compliant)? I am porting a large code base.

```
void foo() {
    extern int i[]; /* gcc -c foo.c gives "incomplete type" error */
    int x;
    i=&x;  }
```

**Update:** I erred on my sample code above. AnT mentions that `i` is not lvalue. Double checking on my older compiler shows this code does **not compile after all**. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: You saw an "older" C compiler that allowed this??? The problem with this code is not really about "empty square brackets". It is about using an array object on the left-hand side of an assignment.

Comment: Name one compiler that permits the assignment `i =  &x` in your code.   I've yet to encounter one.    I have encountered plenty of beginners who insist it is valid code on the basis of the incorrect premise "a pointer is an array and an array is a pointer".

Comment: No, gcc can not be made to allow this.  What is it even supposed to mean?  Is this a realistic excerpt from your "large code base"?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to do a regexp replace across the code base to fix all of these.

Comment: @Barmar And especially if gcc helpfully flags them all as errors. :-)

Comment: It comes from the C language so every C compiler will behave exactly the same.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Apparently it's an "extension" of those other compilers, so the OP could reasonably expect that GCC has a similar extension.

Comment: So those extensions create a new language which is not C anymore.

Comment: @PeterJ_01, You're pretty messed up and your point is meaningless if you don't consider `gcc` a C compiler. Have fun in your ivory tower.

Comment: @PeterJ_01:The C standard explicitly invites extensions and defines programs that use them as “conforming” programs (a distinct category from “strictly conforming” programs).

Comment: Come to think of it, treating extern int i[] as extern int *i is not all that bad. It's more in the realm of buggy compiler than extension but it makes sense when you remember it's a pointer if you had int foo(int []i){}.

Comment: Sorry! GRC reminded me "i" is not an lvalue.  I "translated" my problem incorrectly to the wrong sample code.  Can someone with higher rep delete this whole Question.  thx

Comment: `i` itself is an lvalue. The pointer result of `i`'s decay is not though. The GCC error message refers to the latter.

Comment: The code comment is misleading: `extern int i[];` is correct, the error comes from the line `i = &x;`

Comment: OP you should un-accept the "answer" below and then delete the question

Comment: @Joshua `extern int i[]` is not in the least like `extern int *i`, and any compiler that treated them the same would be attempting the impossible. The former is a variable whose address is the array. The second is a variable whose *value* is an address.

Comment: @infoq You can delete your own question, and you should.

Comment: @EJP: I am aware of the breakage. It reads like containable damage to me, as in it doesn't make the rest of the compiler automatically suspect providing the following didn't compile: extern int i[]; int i[30];

Comment: @Joshua I have no ideas what you're talking about. No compiler with such a breakage is usable.

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of any way to make `gcc` accept such code -- the next best solution I would suggest would be to see if you can use a regular expression replace as @Barmar suggested (it should be relatively easy to check the results, since it does not compile currently); or maybe even try a [Coccinelle semantic patch](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) for a safer approach:

> Coccinelle is a program matching and transformation engine which provides the language SmPL (Semantic Patch Language) for specifying desired matches and transformations in C code.
>
> Coccinelle was initially targeted towards performing collateral evolutions in Linux. Such evolutions comprise the changes that are needed in client code in response to evolutions in library APIs, and may include modifications such as renaming a function, adding a function argument whose value is somehow context-dependent, and reorganizing a data structure.
>
> Beyond collateral evolutions, Coccinelle is successfully used (by us and others) for finding and fixing bugs in systems code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, as the array is not a pointer. In some cases it can behave like a pointer, but it is not a pointer.